# Jquery tabs not working inside of dialog

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery dialog and want to integrate some tabs inside, but the tabs are not working. On the page that has the link to open the dialog, I have JQuery loaded. JQuery doe not seem to be loaded within the dialog though.

Do I need to include my inline JavaScript script tags again? Doesn't the dialog inherit the JQuery library from the page beneath it?

EDIT:

Here is what I am loading into the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#admin").tabs();
  });
</script>
<div id="admin">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab1">
    tab1
  </div>

  <div id="tab2">
    tab2
  </div>

  <div id="tab3">
    tab3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to initialize the tabs after you open the dialog, otherwise the tabs won't initialize properly.

Comment: @KevinB, Thanks Kevin. I'm going to post my code above. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @NaN Your code looks incomplete, you only seem to be covered the "tabs" part of the code. How are you setting up the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed to work OK for me, you're going to need to post your code if you need further assistance. The only thing I had to do was specify an increased height and width to the dialog so the contents displayed better.

The only complication I can think of is if you're loading the contents of the dialog via AJAX, then `$(document).ready()` probably isn't going to initialise the tabs properly.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/geekman/9WBJt/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#modal').dialog({
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
    });
});
```

### Loading Dialog Contents dynamically

This is an edit, based on the additional information you've provided.

So your basic idea would be to do something like this:

1. Click the link/button, this will fire off your code to grab the content for the dialog
2. Hopefully the code you have allows you to pass what's known as a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_function). This is where you can specify a function that will be automatically called once your content has finished loading (or whatever other task).
3. In your callback function, you could then initialise the tabs and display the dialog.

So something like this:

```
<button type="button" id="my-link">Load Me!</button>
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialog-content">
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-link').click(function () {
        //Begin loading your content however you do it.
        //In this case I'm using AJAX because it's one of the most common ways to dynamically load content in JavaScript
        $.get('http://url-to-your-content.com/my-template', '',
            //We can use an anonymous function as our callback function, or define it seperately then call it here.
            //$.get() will call it, and put the contents of my-template in the result variable for us to use.
            function (result) {
                //Insert the result into the div ID dialog-content (I'm assuming the fetched data is HTML).
                var dialog_content = $('#dialog-content');
                dialog_content.html(result);
                //Now, render the HTML in dialog-content as JUI tabs
                dialog_content.tabs();
                //How display your dialog box
                $('#dialog').dialog();
            }, 'html');
    });

    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#modal').dialog({
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pulling the dialog content in through a templating system. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: @Nan Sure you can. Just enable the Scripts tab and set a break-point in the appropriate point in your JavaScript, then step through the code as you would any other debugger.

Comment: @Nan It's hard to say if the templating engine is affecting anything without seeing the code. I can't imagine why, as long as the HTML and Javascript are all getting munged together at the same time, before the page is loaded. I suggest you include the code you're using to setup your jQuery UI dialog box.

Comment: @Nan OK. So from what you're saying, the templating engine dynamically loads the tabs into the dialog box only once the link is clicked, not during the initial page load? In that case, I believe document ready isn't going to help you there. Are you able to setup a call-back for when the template engine finishes loading the content, and only then render/show your dialog?

Comment: Thanks again, Geekman. Your're right, the content is dynamically loaded AFTER the initial page load. Here's the thing, I'm really new to JQuery, getting better every day, but I'm ashamed to admit I really don't know what to include in the callback. :(  Is there an example you can point me to? What would it need to do?

Comment: @Nan I've updated my answer to include a basic (untested) example. If you can show how you're loading your content dynamically, I can give you a better example.

Comment: thanks again for staying the course with me. So, the basic premise is that the dialog content must be loaded before `$('#tabs').tabs();` is called, right?

Comment: @Nan Yes, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the dialog content must be loaded straight away, you just have to jump through more hoops if it's not. So it would be: Load Content -> Insert to Div -> `tabs()` -> `dialog()`

Comment: Geekman, thank you for your example. I've got it now. Thank you again, you've really helped me out on this one!

Comment: Geekman, if you're still around, I've tried your example and was able to get it working, however, the dialog will only open one time, after that, I would need to refresh the browser to be able to get another dialog come up.

Comment: @Nan Should probably post it as a new question, as a long list of comments is not really ideal. If you want to then tag me in a comment somewhere so I get notified, I will check back later. Do you need to open the same dialog multiple times, or do you just need to be able to close and re-open it?

Comment: thanks for responding. I've given up on the tabs. Too much hassle. I've got 3 forms I wanted to use in tabs but now I've got 3 links that open 3 different dialogs. Problem solved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i did this :

```
$("#try").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      open: function (){
            var url = "view.html";
            $("#try").load(url, function(){
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            }); 
      },
});
$("#open_tab").click(function() {
     $("#try").dialog('open');
     }
);
```

index.html :

```
<div id="try" title="Tabs On Dialog">
</div><input type="submit" id="open_tab" value="Open">
```

view.html :

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
    test 1
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
    test 2
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
    test 3
</div>
```